# Applying for a job or an internship

Tags: job-search

After graduating from university with a Physics degree I worked for a year in manufacturing. Here I was involved with a project doing a lot of database programming and statistical analysis. Since then I've returned to school and am working on a MS in CS. I'm set to graduate in the spring, so I am looking to put in applications to places recruiting university grads. I am looking at IT, software engineering jobs etc.

I'm wondering though, that even with some experience in my past job, that, since I am entering a new industry, whether I should be looking at an internship instead of a job. I will be graduated by the time I would start the internship. So I will be effectively looking for a job when the internship completes.

My concern is that if I were to apply to university graduate entry-level jobs, whether I'd be at a disadvantage in begin considered without having had some experience via an internship.

Answer (score 1):

An internship would certainly be helpful to demonstrate industry experience related to your current direction. It could improve your chances, but certainly you can do without it. In this case you would want to highlight your skills in software development through your projects in your Master's program. You could also consider contributing to open-source software development as it is also highly recognized in the industry. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This could depend a lot on your local.
But in the US the IT sector there are more job openings than available applicants so taking a internship when there are jobs available seems like falling on your own sword a bit. But if there are only internships available then it is a good way to get experience.

Also your experience seems to be industry related (DB programming). So this is real world experience you do actually bring to the table. Also going back to Uni for an MSc makes you even more valuable.

In the IT industry your experience (Industrial and Academic) are what get you in the door (with your Resume (CV)); but in the end it will be your in person interview that gets you the job and how you answer the questions.